# Symfony2/Doctrine submiting form takes a really long time

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

We're having problems with creating a small entity using Symfony2 and Doctrine, it works but it's very slow and memory exhausting.

We believe that the problem lies within Symfony's `$form->submit()`.

This takes ~0.1 seconds:

```
die('x');
$form->submit($request);
```

This takes ~60 seconds:

```
$form->submit($request);
die('x');
```

We have tried to "die()" inside this submit method, all the way down to `return $this;` and the run time is roughly 0.1 seconds. It seems like something else is happening behind the scenes and we can't locate the problem.

Running XDebug tells us the following:
Symfony\Component\Form\Form->submit has the highest inclusive cost and mainly this call: Symfony\Component\Form\Form->viewToNorm.

We have tried the following:

- Set realpath_cache_size = 4096k
- Set realpath_cache_ttl=7200
- Disabled XDebug
- Enabled APC

No difference in dev or prod environment.

Comment: Are you sure you're not "falling" into an infinite loop? BTW, with this snippet of code: `die('x');$form->submit($request);` you will never reach $form->submit($request); hope you're know that

Comment: Thanks for your reply. We don't think it's an infinite loop since the entity is created in the database and the id is returned. Regarding die(), we were trying to illustrate that the problem relies within the submit method.

Comment: Are you using a windows server?  I had like a mystery problem like this in which the web server was trying to access a file system that did not exist.  Consider testing with the builtin php web server.  By the way, the stopwatch component is handy for timing things.  http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/stopwatch.html.  Logging is also effective.

Comment: Do you have any `DataTransformer` attached to your form. In any case it would be great to see what's going in your form? Can you paste in the `FormType` for this ominous form?

Comment: Thanks for your reply. It's a linux server, i will look into  Stopwatch.

Comment: We have no custom DataTransformer attached to the form, but during debugging we found out that the  `Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\DataTransformer\ChoiceToValueTransformer` is used and causes the bad performance.

Comment: We solved it by adding query_builder to our form builder and now everything works fine again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We solved it by adding query_builder to our form builder and now everything works fine again.

From:

```
->add('authentication', 'entity', array(
    'class' => 'Model\Authentication',
    'required' => false,
    'multiple' => false,
    'property' => 'id',
    'invalid_message' => _('No authentication entity found')    
))
```

to:

```
->add('authentication', 'entity', array(
    'class' => 'Model\Authentication',
     'required' => false,
     'multiple' => false,
     'property' => 'id',
     'invalid_message' => _('No authentication entity found'),
     'query_builder' => function (EntityRepository $er) {
          return $er
              ->createQueryBuilder('au')
              ->select('au')
          ;
      }    
))
```